# Style Wordpress LOGIN widget

Tags: css, wordpress, authentication, widget

I am trying to find a way to style the default WP-login widget with some CSS. The problem though, is that no matter the selector or class that I use, I simply have 0 effect in the end.

I am aiming to remove the borders on the top, left and right; so only the bottom is left (like an underline), as well as put the 3 fields inline with eachother (username, password, sign in).

Anyone have an idea of what can be done?

**Link to website in question**: dev.melliandshayne.com

**location of login**: Currently I set it to the footer so it's easier to find. I would have it somewhere in the middle of the page at one point though.

**Current theme**: Ronneby Wordpress theme

Many many thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

inspect the element with firebug or some sort of code inspector then you will be able to see the class/id that's applied to the element.

```css
.widget.widget_crum_login form p.login-submit .button,
.widget.widget_crum_login form p.login-password input[type=password],
.widget.widget_crum_login form p.login-username input[type=text]{
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.widget.widget_crum_login form p.login-submit {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will align them side by side as requested...

```
p.login-submit, p.login-username, p.login-password {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: 33% !important;
}
.widget.widget_crum_login form p.login-submit .button, .widget.widget_crum_login form p.login-password input[type="password"], .widget.widget_crum_login form p.login-username input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
.login-lost-password,
.login-remember {
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to find it using Chrome's Inspect Element feature. Thanks for the code!! :) I will apply it now and see what the result is :)

Comment: The buttons width issue was caused by the wrapping `<p>` tag which had a width of 50% applied. So setting that p tag to 100% fixed the width issue.

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, that seemed to do the trick for the Login button itself. Yet I still find myself struggling to find the exact selectors for the fields :( any thoughts here?

Comment: Ive updated my answer to include the email and name fields. Also included the selector the site uses for the other button in the footer. i.e. the subscribe button.

Comment: If this works for you would you kindly click the tick/check mark next to my answer please. :)

Comment: Hi Aaron, 
Sorry I had to run out of the house for a bit. Thanks so much for the help! im going to give it a go right now! and will post my results! :)

Huge thanks!

Comment: Hi Aaron, 
Unfortunately nothing much changed :( It seems the CSS is only affecting the Login Button. Nothing else. 
Thansk so much for the help hey. Perhaps I can be slightly more specific in terms that my aim is to only affect the Login form. All other forms (including Gravity forms, contact form 7 etc...) should not be affected. Is that possible? :)

Comment: Absolutely, Ive updated my answer again @ShayneThomas

Comment: Aaron! Thank you so so much!! The only thing left is to try and make it appear inline to each other? so instead of Username & password beneath one another, have them appear side by side, same with the button?? Don't worry too much if this takes too much of your time. I do appreciate so much of what you've done already!

Comment: Again updated my answer. If you could mark this as correct once tested please. :)

Comment: Aaron! You are a LEGEND! Thank you thank you thank you! Marking as Solved! :)